# Probability of $P(A=1)$ given the probability of their union

Tags: probability

Assume that A and B are binary variables, and that $P(A=1 \cup B=1) = 0.7$ and $P(A=1 \cup B=0) = 1.0$.

**What is the value of $P(A=1)$**?

---

**My attempt**:

$$P(A=1) + P(B=1) = 0.7\\ P(A=1) + P(B=0) = 1.0 \\ We~~have:~P(B=1) + P(B=0) = 1.0\\ \rightarrow P(A=1) = \frac{0.7}{2.0} = 0.35$$

---

**Options**:

- 0.5
- 0.7
- 0.4
- 0.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the intersection $\cap$:

$$\Pr(A=1 \cup B=1)=\Pr(A=1)+\Pr(B=1)-\Pr(A=1\cap B=1)$$
$$\Pr(A=1 \cup B=0)=\Pr(A=1)+\Pr(B=0)-\Pr(A=1\cap B=0)$$
so
$$1.7=2\Pr(A)+1-\Pr(A=1\cap B=1)-\Pr(A=1\cap B=0)$$
Since $\Pr(A=1)=\Pr(A=1\cap B=0)+\Pr(A=1\cap B=1)$ we get $0.7=\Pr(A)$.

Comment: Thanks. Honestly I did not forget about the intersection but when I reached the same line before the last in your solution, I totally forgot about $\Pr(A=1)=\Pr(A=1\cap B=0)+\Pr(A=1\cap B=1)$, That's why I assumed that they are independent.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\begin{align}P(A\cup\overline B) &=1-P(B)\\ 1&=1-P(B)\\ \implies P(B) &=0 \end{align}$$
Hence, you get $$P(A\cup B)=P(A)=0.7$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{cases}
a_1+b_1-(a_1,b_1)=0.7 \\
a_1+b_0-(a_1,b_0)=1
\end{cases}$$

summing member to member you get

$$2a_1+\underbrace{(b_0+b_1)}_{=1}-\underbrace{[(a_1,b_1)+(a_1,b_0)]}_{=a_1}=1.7$$

$$a_1=0.7$$

Notation:

- $a_i=P(A=i)$
- $a_ib_j=P(A=i \cap B=j)$